# Populate select list with contacts

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to use a apex:selectList to populate contacts. The problem is that it gives an error

```
  Collection size 3,403 exceeds maximum size of 1,000
```

This is because i have 3403 contacts, and Vf has limitation on the collections in the VF page.

I want to limit the inital set of contacts to <1000, and as the user starts typing in the characters i would want to query the contacts. For ex if the user types in Ji i want to query the contacts to retrieve records starting with JI.

Is this possible to do?

```
  <apex:selectlist id="ClientsSearch"  value="{!Appointment.Client__c}" 
       size="1" required="true" rendered="{!NOT (SearchMode)}">

  <apex:selectOptions value="{!Clients}" />
  </apex:selectlist>


 public List<SelectOption> getClients() {     
   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
  List<Contact> Clients =  [Select id, Name From Contact order by Name];
  options.add(new SelectOption('0001', '--Select--'));
 for(Contact c : Clients ){
 options.add(new  SelectOption(c.id, c.Name));
 }
  return options;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wild cards in your query to do this — so you'll want to add an `<apex:inputText>` element in your page to allow them to enter a search term, which writes to a string variable in the controller. Then add a search button to run the query and re-render the list with the new list of contacts.

The important parts of the controller will look something like this:

```
public string SearchTerm {get; set;}
public list<ContacT> Contacts {get; set;}

public Pagereference SearchContacts()
{
    // etc.
    Contacts = [select Id, Name from Contact where name like : '%' + SearchTerm + '%' order by name limit 1000]; 
    // populate list here
    return null;
}
```

You could perform the search using an action function and firing it from the onChange event of the input field but having a button to do the search will make the whole thing more response (IMO) from the user's point of view.

Note: I wrote this code on the fly, it may be that you can't just concat '%' with the search term in this manner or maybe that you don't even need to when querying directly. Usually in these cases I've had to utilise dynamic SOQL due to other requirements, where you build up the query in a string:

```
strQuery = 'select id from contact where name like \'%' +
    String.escapeSingleQuotes(SearchTerm) + '%\' order by name';
for(Contact sContact : Database.query(strQuery) ...
```

Comment: Thanks @LaceySnr  I was trying to have this functionality on a select or dropdown. The idea was to restrict the no of contacts which the user can select from dropdown as binding all the contacts was giving the error Collection size 3,403 exceeds maximum size of 1,000. 
I could very well use the lookup to search for contacts, client wanted to see if we could this kind of functionality on a select

Comment: Ah I think you misunderstood me a little... the idea is that you use this query to fill the list of contacts in the selectlist in the same way that you do now. For the initial display of the screen just run the search with nothing, the limit 1000 will prevent the other error. If there are 1000 results, maybe add a message to the page to indicate to the user that the list is limited. Even 1000 seems like a very big list though!

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that i have an <apex:inputText> along with the select and have call a method on keyup or onchange which runs the query and rerenders the select? Could we do this on the select itself instead of <apex:inputText>

Comment: i guess that wont be possible as the select list doesnt allow input :(

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately VisualForce doens't have a combo-box style element. You can do them with some jQuery plugins and funky javascript but to be honest it gets to be so messy it's not worth the bother.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to get the functionality you'd like. It depends on how complicated of a solution you'd like, but there is always a solution.

You may want to consider using jQuery and SOSL (Search Language) in a controller. Here's an example of jQuery autocomplete with the Ajax API in Salesforce. Click the link below:
http://matthewkeefe-developer-edition.na8.force.com/jQueryAutocompleteWithAjaxAPI

Also, check out Tehnrd's post "[Super Cool Advanced Lookup Component](http://www.tehnrd.com/super-cool-advanced-lookup-component/)" for another option.